# urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found python

Tags: python, json, urllib2, urllib

My code is supposed to get from specific json like url (output webpage is offering is not JSON which is required). When I get it with connection A it returns me following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\nihadazimli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "G:/Internship/quantsol-text/web-crawler/mynet_new/date_gaining.py", line 20, in run
        main_func(self.counter)
      File "G:/Internship/quantsol-text/web-crawler/mynet_new/date_gaining.py", line 166, in main_func
        total=url_to_dict(url)
      File "G:/Internship/quantsol-text/web-crawler/mynet_new/date_gaining.py", line 79, in url_to_dict
        data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
      File "C:\Users\nihadazimli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 163, in urlopen
        return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
      File "C:\Users\nihadazimli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 472, in open
        response = meth(req, response)
      File "C:\Users\nihadazimli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 582, in http_response
        'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
      File "C:\Users\nihadazimli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 510, in error
        return self._call_chain(*args)
      File "C:\Users\nihadazimli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "C:\Users\nihadazimli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 590, in http_error_default
        raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Interestingly, when I try to get info with connection B it works fine however i get following error after 10000-20000 iterations:

```
Exception in thread Thread-9:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nihadazimli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1254, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
  File "C:\Users\nihadazimli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 1106, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Users\nihadazimli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 1151, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Users\nihadazimli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 1102, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Users\nihadazimli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 934, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\nihadazimli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 877, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\nihadazimli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 849, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\Users\nihadazimli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\socket.py", line 711, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\nihadazimli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\socket.py", line 702, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

I searched several hours internet for error with connection B Error with connection B mainly occurs because of connection problem or proxy. I tried this solution with several different proxies it did not work either gave the same error after some thousand iterations:

```
 proxy_support = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({"http": "http://208.83.106.105:9999"})
 opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_support)
 urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
```

The problematic part is following :

```
class myThread (threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)
      self.threadID = threadID
      self.name = name
      self.counter = counter
    def run(self):
       main_func(self.counter)

def url_to_dict(url):
    hdr = {
        'User-Agent': 'Chrome/60.0.3112.101 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/537.11 Mozilla/55.0.2',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive'}


    data2= urllib.request.Request(url,headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    # proxy_support = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({"http": "http://61.233.25.166:80"})
    # opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support)
    # urllib2.install_opener(opener)



    data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
    json_type_string = re.findall('({.*})', data)[0]
    json_data = json.loads(json_type_string)
    total_page = json_data['data']['totalPage']
    return json_data,total_page


def main_func(counter):
    proxy_support = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({"http": "http://208.83.106.105:9999"})
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_support)
    urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
    for x in range(len(url_list)):
        url=url_list[x]
        company_name=company_list[x]
        total=url_to_dict(url)
        total_page=total[1]
        for y in range(int(total_page/10)):
            index = url.find('config[page]=')
            index2 = url.find('&config[reply')
            k = y*10

            url = url[:index+13] + str(counter+k) + url[index2:]
            print(url)
            data = url_to_dict(url)
            parsed_data = get_data(data)
            add_to_mongo(parsed_data,company_name)
```

Comment: This question doesn't have a question. You're unlikely to get much of a response until then. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also, in your first code block, it looks like you need to fix the line beginning " Interestingly, when I try to get info with connection B..." because it's flowed into an adjacent code block. Add a new line before that, and remove the indentation spaces.